# Separate media server

Tags: django

I have one web server, one db server and one file server. Web and db servers works fine, but I want to place all media files (photos, etc) on file server. Architecture is like that:

[image: Architecture]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095481/django-how-to-setup-separate-media-static-server-on-shared-hosting) and [this](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html), but I cant find instructions, how to do this. If someone has already done it, share experiences and code, please :)

Thanks.

Comment: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ might be of use to you.  I use it to host static and media files on S3.